# Warning: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript

I'm checking out the documentation source file [index.js](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/index.js) from [this library](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker). I checked up the code in jshint, and there's a warning saying:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

File: [index.js Line: 215](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/index.js#L215)

```
s = (Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y)) / r) * 100;
```

Why am I getting the warning, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is it because commas rather than semicolons separate that and the preceding lines?

Comment: @Horay This link might help you better understand the intent of the message you received: https://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Liu is correct.  At [the jshint website](http://jshint.com/), replacing the commas with semi-colons gets rid of the warning:

```
function main() {
  var currentTargetHeight = 240;
  var e = {clientX: 40, clientY: 50};
  var startPoint = { left: 3, right: 4};
  var r, x, y, h, s;
  r = currentTargetHeight / 2;
  x = e.clientX - startPoint.left - r;
  y = e.clientY - startPoint.top - r;
  h = 360 - ((Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI) + (y < 0 ? 360 : 0));
  s = (Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y)) / r) * 100;
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! Why did the author do it using commas?

Comment: They probably were trying to define multiple variables as one statement.  This would have been valid:  `var r = currentTargetHeight / 2, x = e.clientX - startPoint.left - r, etc...`